# problem with U-boot while flashing Linux in sd-card

Tags: gnu-screen, serial-port, u-boot, angstrom, serial-console

Please help as it is immense necessary for a project which is to be evaluated coming  week. Also, I am very new to this and unable to find help from existing contents available on the Internet.

While flashing Angstrom Linux on Toradex's Colibri T30 `Iris board`, I am receiving a very peculiar problem in which no auto-booting starts and there doesn't appear any U-boot bootloader prompt; though it is expected from the steps taken.

> When I have to flash the image to that board from the image already
>   available in the sd-card, it has been suggested to use any utilities
>   like `screen`, `gtkterm/etc.`.

What has been suggested on their website is to use command like

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200                    # here 115200 is the baud-rate.
```

I checked the confirm presence of my serial-pin to usb-adapter. It  is working and identified as `/dev/ttyUSB0` from `dmesg | less`. SO, every step before the flashing is working fine. Just as I use the above mentioned screen command on Ubuntu 13.10, it just goes to a blank screen in the terminal and no-such flashing starts taking place.

There doesn't appear any auto-booting step which has been mentioned on the [Toradex's developer website](http://developer1.toradex.com/files/toradex-dev/uploads/media/Colibri/Linux/Images/Colibri_T30_LinuxReleaseNotesV2.x.txt). I have waited for even 10 minutes but only to find no result. The screen just goes to a null-state with terminal kind of thing visible with no content and I have to exit that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to exit screen utulity on Ubuntu. Also, the bootloader of the board is working fine as there is already an old-version of Angstrom-Linux booting. We just wanted to upgrade the custom Linux provided by Colibri_Toradex...

If someone knows why this problem is happening, AND what would be the possible solution to it??? I'll highly appreciate his/her response.

Comment: Have you tried [`minicom`](https://alioth.debian.org/projects/minicom)?

Comment: @peterph-Yeah, I tried minicom,gtkterm and one more too! Everywhere failure! Please help somehow!

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention using a null modem with your serial cable, perhaps that is why you never see anything in the terminal.

Since the device is booting, then U-boot is working properly.  Your serial settings are correct as defined in to the release notes and the [serial console instructions provided on the Toradex developer website](http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/how-to-disable-enable-debug-messages-in-linux#Entering_into_Uboot_prompt).

Ensure that you use a null modem in your DTE-to-DTE connection.  You should see lots of output on the serial terminal even during the normal boot sequence.

Comment: Thanks SIR. I'll check this and let you know exactly. But, I am really aware of this null modem thing! I used an RS232 cable to connect! If it is possible for you to attach an image OR send a link for such item, please help. THANKS really...

Comment: I often use a null modem adapter [such as this](http://www.amazon.com/Bargain-Cable-Female-Modem-Adapter/dp/7507825604/ref=sr_1_6?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1427833106&sr=1-6&keywords=null+modem).  I also often use a [FTDI USB-to-serial cable with a built in null modem](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008634VJY/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_2?pf_rd_p=1944687762&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B000DZH4V0&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=1NQGTF7EM74YK48SXPVT).  There are also [null modem serial cables](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00DRQNFRY?psc=1).  Best of luck to you.