# basic serial communication

Tags: serial-port

I've inserted a serial USB to TTL device to serially talk to my microcontroller when I inserted the device I got a file in `dev` directory named `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

So now I want to communicate through it by writing a C program so I want to know how to set baud rate on it and how to read and write directly through it without using `minicom`, `screen` or other third part tool.

Comment: Use `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` #where 115200 is the baud rate... Here,screen is the utility to view the serial communication.

Comment: Check this--->http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169444/problem-with-u-boot-while-flashing-linux-in-sd-card

Comment: Look at the termios(3) man page. read(2) and write(2) to read and write. Programming questions are for stackoverflow.